# Is str.split() vulnerable to denial of service attacks?

Tags: python-3.x, django, regex, sonarqube, sonarlint

I have a base64 uri that I want to capture and process from a POST request:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    image_data = request.POST.get('signature_base64', None)
    imgformat, imgstr = image_data.split(';base64,')
```

However, my code linter ([SonarCloud](https://sonarcloud.io/)) flags this as potentially exposed as a DoS attack.

> Regular expressions can have an exponential execution time depending
> on the pattern and the length of the input string. The example below,
> for instance, can lead to a denial of service of the application:
>
> Pattern: `/(a+)+b/` Input string:
> `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacb`

> It is recommended: to fix the hard-coded regex patterns that use CPU intensive features
> (avoid if possible captures, nested quantifiers and back-references,
> for instance replace the above pattern with (/a+b/)). when the regex
> pattern is defined with an user-controlled input, this last should be
> sanitized in order to escape characters which are part of the regular
> expression syntax.

I am unsure how I would go about preventing this. Is the linter correct? What would be best practice in this case?

Comment: Plain string splitting does not use regular expressions.

Comment: @JohnGordon, thanks. Could this simply be an error in SonarQube?

Comment: Do not pay attention to these messages unless they stop your code from executing. If your regex is static or is defined by you, these are just scarecrows for regex laymen.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, that's helpful context. In this case as this is a request.POST I guess the `str` is defined by the user, so I would like to debug it if possible.

Comment: But is the *regex* also defined by the user?

Answer (score 0):

Putting the regex thing aside, `split()` itself has a potential denial attack in the following case:

```
user_input = ';string;with;many;parts;;;;;;;;;;'

for part in user_input.split(';'):
    # many iterations
    # eats a lot of CPU resources
```

One solution is to limit the split with the `maxsplit` parameter, which will limit the number of iterations. Or apply `sleep` every iteration.